# Custom jQuery plugin doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery

I tried to create my own tiny jQuery plugin to fill and clear a textarea:

```
$.fn.fillTextarea = function ( startVal ) {
    var messBox = $(this).val(startVal);

    messBox.on('focus blur', function () {
        var curVal = $.trim($(this).val());
        if (curVal == startVal) {
            $(this).val('');
        } else if (!curVal) {
            $(this).val(startVal);
        }
    });
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.number-1').fillTextarea({
        'startVal' : 'test'
    });
});
```

But when I try to use it I get `[object Object]` in the textarea instead of my startVal.
http://jsfiddle.net/3QHWe/1/

What's wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ( startVal ) {
       // ^ is object which is passed
```

to get the it's key value value use `object.key`

```
$('.number-1').fillTextarea({
    'startVal' : 'test'
    //^Key        Value
```

Use `startVal.startVal` to get value that is `text`

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wQmjR/)